# Остановить программу при срабатывании assert

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, исключения

У меня многопоточное приложение. При каких-то манипуляциях в основном потоке в дополнительном потоке срабатывает assert и появляется сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом программа продолжает работать. В итоге я не могу отловить какие действия в основном потоке приводят к проблеме.

Можно ли как-то отключить это диалоговое окно, чтобы программа сразу останавливалась и меня выбрасывало в отладчик?

В идеале если бы это отключение работало только при запуске из под отладчика, но это требование не критично.

Comment: Так кнопка "повтор" открывает отладчик

Comment: @gbg Так пока я ее нажму, в главном потоке выполнится пара сотен операторов

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51919433/5376639

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ нашел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51919732/5376639)

Нужно при старте программы вызвать

```c
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
```

Заголовочный файл `<crtdbg.h>`